# Php Symfony 3.1 exception by using Doctrine DBAL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to use Doctrine DBAL in my Symfony web project.

What I've done:

Config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_pgsql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: my_project_db
    database_user: postgres
    database_password: my_password
```

My controller for company profile

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/{userId}/{sessionKey}", name="profile")
 */

public function profileAction($userId=null, $sessionKey=null)
{
    $securityController = new SecurityController();
    $securityController->userId = $userId;
    $securityController->sessionKey = $sessionKey;
    if ($securityController->sessionKeyIsValid())
    {
        return new Response('Profile');
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
    }
}
```

And my securityController where I'm trying to connect to my Postresql

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public $userId;
    public $sessionKey;

    public function sessionKeyIsValid()
    {
        $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
        //$conn->fetchAll('select * from main.users;');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Exception (`Error: Call to a member function get() on null`) appears on this string of code `$conn = $this->get('database_connection');`
What I'm doing wrong? It seems that I followed step by step as is it advised in Symfony cookBook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Symfony project, you **never** instantiate yourself a controller. If you want to separate your logic from your controller, [create a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and inject what you need as a dependency.

Your service for instance may look like this :

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class SecurityService 
{
    protected $db;
    public $userId;
    public $sessionKey;

    public function __construct(Connection $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function sessionKeyIsValid()
    {
        // $this->db->fetchAll('select * from main.users;');
    }
}
```

And you declare it in your `services.yml` like this :

```
services:
    app_security:
       class:        AppBundle\Service\SecurityService
       arguments:   [ "@database_connection" ]
```

Then, in any controller, you have access to a shared instance of `SecurityService` :

```
public function profileAction($userId=null, $sessionKey=null)
{
    $security = $this->get('app_security');

    // ...
}
```

I must warn you however that accessing directly to the database layer is probably not the correct way. You should read the [Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) section from the documentation first.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, but I didn't get so far how to link service argument (arguments:   [ "@database_connection" ]) with database connection parameters described in my parameters.yml file. If I took your example "as is" I get error (Unable to parse at line 15 (near " arguments: [ "@database_connection" ]").)

Comment: There was a non wanted space in my previous response, I fixed it. The syntax `"@database_connection"` means inject the service named `database_connection` through the constructor. It has already been instantiated, see your `config.yml` near `doctrine` section, you will find your database parameters already registered. You should really read the sections of the documentation you are interested in. Symfony is a very powerful tool, but it is clearly counterproductive if not used appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved by removing extra space as you mentioned. I didn't know that yml config so depends on formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Container is not set, so you cann't call its methods.

```
$securityController = new SecurityController();
$securityController->userId = $userId;
$securityController->sessionKey = $sessionKey
$securityController->setContainer($this->container);
```

I think that it is not good idea to use `SecurityController` as controller, it is a service.